# TItanium Webview webkit not registered

Tags: webview, titanium

I am using Titanium Appcelerator for android. I had created a window with webview and a button , when i attempt to navigate from that page by clicking that button or using "android:back" , app gets crashed.

1. I guessing webview blocking to close window..

**MY CODE**

```
var webview1 = Titanium.UI.createWebView({
    url : 'https://www.google.com/',
    height : '85%',
    width : '90%'
});

if (isIphone) {
    webview1.setWillHandleTouches(true);
} else {
    webview1.setPluginState(Ti.UI.Android.WEBVIEW_PLUGINS_ON);
    webview1.setEnableZoomControls(true);
}
```

*[**WARNING**] :

> [WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 5803: Landroid/webkit/WebSettings;.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs (Z)V
>   [WARN] :   webview: java.lang.Throwable: Warning: A WebView method was called on thread 'WebViewCoreThread'. All WebView methods must be called on the UI thread. Future versions of WebView may not support use on other threads.
>   [WARN] :   webview:     at android.webkit.WebView.checkThread(WebView.java:9355)
>   [WARN] :   webview:     at android.webkit.WebView.getSettings(WebView.java:4053)
>   [WARN] :   webview:     at android.webkit.ZoomManager.getReadingLevelScale(ZoomManager.java:317)
>   [WARN] :   webview:     at android.webkit.WebView.getReadingLevelScale(WebView.java:2448)
>   [WARN] :   webview:     at android.webkit.WebViewCore.setupViewport(WebViewCore.java:2487)
>   [WARN] :   webview:     at android.webkit.WebViewCore.didFirstLayout(WebViewCore.java:2258)
>   [WARN] :   webview:     at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeSetSize(Native Method)
>   [WARN] :   webview:     at android.webkit.WebViewCore.viewSizeChanged(WebViewCore.java:1892)
>   [WARN] :   webview:     at android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$2200(WebViewCore.java:55)
>   [WARN] :   webview:     at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub$1.handleMessage(WebViewCore.java:1227)
>   [WARN] :   webview:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   [WARN] :   webview:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   [WARN] :   webview:     at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:722)
>   [WARN] :   webview:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
>   [INFO] :   TiAnalyticsSvc: (Thread-98) [48405,57879] Analytics Service Started

Comment: This error prompt when button is clicked?
Can you post the code in button's click event handler too?

Comment: Instead of taking screenshot of whole traceback copy it and paste here using code formatting.

Comment: @Bowie: I removed my button also.. now also getting same

Comment: When i try it in my device.. i getting the unregister error as warning..And No crashed..But there is nothing displaying in webview..